# Send SMS with wifi on Android

Tags: android, sockets, android-emulator, android-wifi

How can I send sms with wifi on android, with socket or ...? I would like send message to one emulator to second emulator. How can I do this?

Comment: to send sms from 1 emulator to the other set the sending number as the other emulators number  which is shown on top of the emulator like :5556,5558 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is used for sending message from one emulator to another.

```
btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
public void onClick(View v)
{
sendSMS("5556", "Hi You got a message!");
}
});

//---sends an SMS message to another device---

private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
}
```

This is used for sending message from one emulator to more than one emulators.

```
btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
   {
     public void onClick(View v)
        {
         Intent i = new
              Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
              i.putExtra("address", "5556; 5558; 5560");
              i.putExtra("sms_body", "Hello my friends!");
              i.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
              startActivity(i);
         }
    });
```

Comment: but I would like send with wifi. What I must know about wifi. may be wifi ip?

Comment: SMS in wifi? No way. You can send a message in wifi by implementing TCP sockets.Or even files in that sense